# Compute slide number in beamer

Tags: beamer

The **MWE** below is to insert some constant content in all odd slides.

Since the number of even slides could change, how to insert the odd contents automatically?

For example, if the last even slide is `\only<10>{This is slide \thepage.}` the command for constant content should be automatically computed to `\only<1,3,...,11>{This is slide \thepage.}`

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\only<1,3,5>{This is slide \thepage. ODD.}
\only<2>  {This is slide \thepage.}
\only<4>  {This is slide \thepage.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you want 'odd in absolute terms' or rather 'relative to a currently even slide', _e.g._ is the `\only<2>` line the 'anchor'. I ask as this feels to me like a case where you want relative slide specifiers.

Comment: @JosephWright, thanks for comment. But I'm afraid I don't understand what you said. For example, what I want is to insert song lyrics, and after each part, show a chorus. I think I will use a single `frame`, so odd/even works well. But it would be nice to extend and apply the rule for `first, first+2, fisrt+4,...` where `first` is the 1st one in the frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\insertonodd}{%
    \ifodd\the\beamer@slideinframe
        This is slide \insertslideinframe. ODD.
    \else
        \only<\numexpr\insertslideinframe+1\relax>{}
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\insertslideinframe}{\the\beamer@slideinframe}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\insertonodd

\only<2>  {This is slide \insertslideinframe.}
\only<4>  {This is slide \insertslideinframe.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

With an up-to-date beamer version, this can be simplified to:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\insertonodd}{%
    \ifodd\insertoverlaynumber
        This is slide \insertoverlaynumber. ODD.
    \else
        \only<\numexpr\insertoverlaynumber+1\relax>{}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\insertonodd

\only<2>  {This is slide \insertoverlaynumber.}
\only<4>  {This is slide \insertoverlaynumber.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Your code works as expected, but I don't understand the logical rule. Since there is no loop within `insertonodd` definition, how it inserts content in slide number 3? I suppose it is executed only once at beginning. Could you give me an idea?

Comment: @Sigur The command is executed once on every overlay

Comment: Is the `\if else fi` responsible for this?

Comment: @Sigur No, every command in the body of a frame is executed once per overlay. You can test this by replacing `\insertonodd` with a counter.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Nice to know. Thanks.